# Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ~/modules/Log/Syslog/Constants.pm line 28

Tags: perl, perl-module

Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ~/modules/Log/Syslog/Constants.pm line 28. 
(F) A value used as either a hard reference or a symbolic reference must
    be a defined value.  This helps to delurk some insidious errors.
Full code is as follows:

```
package Log::Syslog::Fast::Constants;

use strict;

use warnings;

use Log::Syslog::Constants ();
use Carp 'croak';

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(Exporter);


use constant LOG_UDP    => 0; # UDP
use constant LOG_TCP    => 1; # TCP
use constant LOG_UNIX   => 2; # UNIX socket


use constant LOG_RFC3164 => 0;
use constant LOG_RFC5424 => 1;

our @EXPORT = ();
our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    protos =>  [qw/ LOG_TCP LOG_UDP LOG_UNIX /],
    formats => [qw/ LOG_RFC3164 LOG_RFC5424 /],
);
$EXPORT_TAGS{$_} = $Log::Syslog::Constants::EXPORT_TAGS{$_}
    for qw(facilities severities);
our @EXPORT_OK = @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{all} } = map {@$_} values %EXPORT_TAGS;

sub AUTOLOAD {
    (my $meth = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://;
    if (Log::Syslog::Constants->can($meth)) {
        return Log::Syslog::Constants->$meth(@_);
    }
    croak "Undefined subroutine $AUTOLOAD";
}

1;
```

Comment: This works fine for me.  What do you do to get that error? Is the placement of this file, `Constants.pm`,correct? The other thought -- apparently there happens to be a module with the exact same name, `use`d by `Log::Syslog::Fast`. Is this related, are there conflicts?

Comment: By "works for me" I mean the following. I `use` this module (in the file `Constants.pm` placed in `Log/Syslog/Fast/`) in a script, and after `use Log::Syslog::Fast::Constants qw(:severities)` I can print the constant (as bareword) `LOG_DEBUG`, etc. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by using a `Log::Syslog::Constants` module that is not compatible with your `Log::Syslog::Constants::Fast` module.

The `::Fast` module is trying to delegate imports to `Log::Syslog::Constants`, but one or more of the delegate import groups (one of the list `qw(facilities severities)`) is not in the `%EXPORT_OK` hash of the `Log::Syslog::Constants` module, meaning that the `::Fast` module pulls in `undef` instead of a value for that field on line 27.

There are a couple of ways that this could happen:

**Possibility 1:** there's an unrelated module calling itself `Log::Syslog::Constants`.

To debug this, do `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(\%INC);` in the `::Fast` module to see what `Constants.pm` is getting loaded, and make sure it's in the same place where the rest of the `Log::Syslog` non-fast module lives.

If it's not, [check your module search path](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations) and make sure that it can find the non-`::Fast` module and that nothing is modifying search locations (e.g. `use lib`) to find something else that calls itself `Log::Syslog::Constants` before the real thing--this would cause a bad module to "shadow" the good one, and always get loaded instead.

**Possibility 2:** The version of `Log::Syslog::Constants` installed on your system is not compatible with the version of `Log::Syslog::Constants::Fast`.

TO debug this, check the source code of `Log::Syslog::Constants` to make sure that both of the delegate import groups are contained in its `%EXPORT_OK`.

If they are not, determine whether or not you should upgrade, downgrade, or change the package source (usually not a great idea) to solve the issue. It may also be solvable by upgrading, downgrading, or changing the `::Fast` module's source as well; whichever you would prefer. You'll need to have a `::Fast` wrapper that is compatible with the non-`::Fast` base version regardless, though.